# How to limit the time DownloadString(url) allowed by 500 milliseconds?

Tags: c#, time, limit, downloadstring

I'm writing a program that when textBox1 change:

```
URL = "http://example.com/something/";
URL += System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(textBox1.Text);
s = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(URL);
```

I want limit the time DownloadString(URL) allowed by 500 milliseconds. If more than, cancel it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is no such property, but you can easily extend the `WebClient`:

```
public class TimedWebClient: WebClient
{
    // Timeout in milliseconds, default = 600,000 msec
    public int Timeout { get; set; }

    public TimedWebClient()
    {
        this.Timeout = 600000; 
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var objWebRequest= base.GetWebRequest(address);
        objWebRequest.Timeout = this.Timeout;
        return objWebRequest;
    }
}

// use
string s = new TimedWebClient {Timeout = 500}.DownloadString(URL);
```

Comment: Had a problem with a popular currency rates site, site allowed conneciton but their API did not send a response - this little nugget is the ideal patch, much obliged.

Comment: Now I look again and learned enough to know your answer diriectly answer my question. Change accecpted to your answer.

Answer (score 7):

One way to do this would be to use the DownloadStringAsync method on the WebClient class, and then asynchronously call the CancelAsync method after 500 milliseconds. See the remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.cancelasync%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for some pointers on how to do that.

Alternatively, you could use the WebRequest class instead, which has a Timeout property. See the code example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponse.aspx#Y555).